# JPA with OpenJPA gives ArgumentException

Tags: jpa, ejb, openjpa, apache-tomee

Following is my Bean

```
package com.dunkul.stateless;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;

import com.dunkul.entity.Book;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@Stateless
public class LibraryPersistentBean implements LibraryPersistentBeanRemote {

   public LibraryPersistentBean(){
   }

   @PersistenceContext(unitName="EjbComponentPU")
   private EntityManager entityManager;         

   public void addBook(Book book) {
      entityManager.persist(book);
   }    

   public List<Book> getBooks() {
      return entityManager.createQuery("From Book").getResultList();
   }
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------


package com.dunkul.stateless;

import javax.ejb.Remote;

import com.dunkul.entity.Book;
import java.util.List;

@Remote
public interface LibraryPersistentBeanRemote {

   void addBook(Book bookName);

   List<Book> getBooks();

}

//----------------------------------------------------------
```

Entity class

```
package com.dunkul.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EntityListeners;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="books")
public class Book implements Serializable{

   private int id;
   private String name;

   public Book(){        
   }

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name="id")
   public int getId() {
      return id;
   }

   public void setId(int id) {
      this.id = id;
   }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }    
}

//-------------------------------------------------
```

persistance.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="EjbComponentPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
        <jta-data-source>TestDS</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.dunkul.entity.Book</class>
    </persistence-unit>
 </persistence>


//--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Client.java

```
    package com.dunkul.client;

    import java.util.Hashtable;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.List;

    import javax.naming.Context;
    import javax.naming.InitialContext;

    import com.dunkul.entity.Book;
    import com.dunkul.stateless.LibraryPersistentBeanRemote;;



    public class ClientEJB {

        LibraryPersistentBeanRemote lib;
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            new ClientEJB().callEjb();
        }
        private void callEjb() throws Exception {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Hashtable<String, String> ctxProps = new Hashtable<String, String>();
            ctxProps.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.openejb.client.RemoteInitialContextFactory");
            ctxProps.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http://localhost:8082/tomee/ejb");
            ctxProps.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES,"org.apache.naming");
            ctxProps.put("openejb.descriptors.output", "true");
            InitialContext context = new InitialContext(ctxProps);
            lib = (LibraryPersistentBeanRemote)context.lookup("LibraryPersistentBeanRemote");
            String bookName = "Sonali";

            Book newBook = new Book();
        //  newBook.setId(1);
        //  newBook.setName(bookName);
        //  lib.addBook(newBook);

            List ls = lib.getBooks();
            for (Iterator iterator = ls.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                Object object = (Object) iterator.next();
                System.out.println((String)object);

            }

        }

    }

I am getting following error
```

SEVERE: EjbTransactionUtil.handleSystemException: "Encountered "From" at character 1, but expected: ["DELETE", "SELECT", "UPDATE"]." while parsing JPQL "From Book". See nested stack trace for
 original parse error.
 org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: "Encountered "From" at character 1, but expected: ["DELETE", "SELECT", "UPDATE"]." while
parsing JPQL "From Book". See nested stack trace for original parse error.

Answer (score 1):

```
"From Book"
```

is **invalid** JPQL (the query language that JPA provides for).

The syntax you used is "Hibernate HQL" and is invalid for JPA. Needless to say that Hibernate docs do not make much of an effort to make this clear and so many people who have used Hibernate think this HQL is what all JPA implementations should support.

Compliant JPA implementations (such as OpenJPA) use JPQL (as any decent JPA tutorial would say). Valid JPQL is something like

```
SELECT b FROM Book b
```

Comment: I have modified the client like bellow

Comment: I modified the code to remove JPQL call and kept only following.
Book newBook = new Book();
        newBook.setId(10);
        newBook.setName(bookName);
        lib.addBook(newBook);
I am getting new exception. 

<openjpa-2.4.0-r422266:1674604 nonfatal store error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityExistsException: Attempt to persist detached object "com.dunkul.entity.Book@679bf6b6".  If this is a
new instance, make sure any version and/or auto-generated primary key fields are null/default when persisting.
FailedObject: com.dunkul.entity.Book@679bf6b6

Comment: which is nothing to do with the original problem, so accept this answer and open a new question with FULL details of this new problem